# Correcting the following question (of Thomae function) and solving the correct version of it.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives

The question say: let $f$ be the Thomae function given below:

[image]

And let $g(x)= \int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt$. Prove that $g'(x) = f(x)$ iff $x \in \mathbb{Q}.$

I was told that the question contain a mistake, but I do not know what is it, could anyone tell me it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of $x\in\mathbb Q$, it should be $x\in[0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q$. The function $g$ is the null function and therefore $g'$ is the null function too. And $f(x)=0$ if and only if $x\in[0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Could you give me a hint for the solution please?

Comment: I already gave.

Comment: why you choose the interval [0,1] specifically?

Comment: why the fuction $g$ is the null function?

Comment: I did not choose the interval $[0,1]$. That's the domain of Thomae's function. And the function $g$ is the null function because for every $a$ and every $b$ in $[0,1]$ such that $a\leqslant b$, $\int_a^bg(x)\,\mathrm dx=0$. **In particular**, $g(x)=0$.

Comment: yeah I am sorry you are correct, it is its domain.

Comment: How do you know that this is the correction of the question?

Comment: Because it is the only error that I was able to find in its statement.

Comment: what is the value of g if x was a rational ?

Comment: It is $0$. Otherwise, I would not have written that $g$ is the null function.

Comment: why the value of g is zero when x is rational?

Comment: may be because of the darboux lower sums  ..... correct?

Comment: Yes. All lower sums are equal to $0$.

Comment: and to be integrable the lower sums must be equal to the upper sums ..... hence the upper sums also are zero , hence the integration is zero .... correct ? as any interval contains rational and irrational numbers .... correct?

Comment: All those statements are correct.

Comment: I think that the correction should be [0,1]\Q  union {0} bacause $f(x) = 0$ also if x=0 ..... correct?

Comment: No, because $f(0)=1$.